# Bitcoin RPC authentication issue - regtest

Tags: json, authentication, rpc, bitcoin, bitcoind

i am currently developing a bitcoin application which involves running a full bitcoin node.

As i am testing my source code, i decided to use the bitcoin regtest mode.

This is how i start my bitcoin node:

```
./bitcoind -regtest -rpcuser=a -rpcpassword=b -server -bind=0.0.0.0
```

This is how i am interacting with my regtest node:

```
./bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=a -rpcpassword=b getnewaddress
```

Output:

```
2N152jpoD9u52cpswsN7ih8RZ3P4DszaUGg
```

This example works as expected... BUT !

As soon as i try to interact with bitcoin node not using *bitcoin-cli*, but curl or python i get stuck:

```
curl --user a --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getnewaddress", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.178.200:18444/
```

i get asked for the password => i enter *b*

and then it says:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

same for:

```
curl --user a:b --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getnewaddress", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.178.200:18444/
```

and:

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getnewaddress", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://a:b@192.168.178.200:18444/
```

I also looked for a cookie file to authenticate with cookie, but there was none.

i already researched the problem, e.g.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22335/bitcoin-daemon-sends-empty-reply-from-server-when-in-test-net

and various other sites, but none helped...

i am running version 0.18.0

Well, i described my problem in detail and mentioned what i already tried for two days..

Any suggestions?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: TRy with -rpcallowip=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

We should update the regtest RPC port if the version is >= **0.16.0** to **18443**.
So, I just changed the port from **18444** to **18443**, it worked.

Example:

`curl --user username:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getblockhash","params":[0]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18443`

Ref: https://github.com/ruimarinho/bitcoin-core/issues/60